# tensor products of Banach space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E_{1},\cdots, E_{n}$ be Banach spaces; $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ be a real numbers and $E\widehat{\otimes}\mathbb{R}$ be a completion tensor product.
We have the fact that $E_{i}\widehat{\otimes}\mathbb{R}\equiv E_{i}$
for all $i=1,\cdots,n$.

Does $E_{1}\widehat{\otimes}\mathbb{R}\times\cdots\times E_{1}\widehat{\otimes}\mathbb{R}\equiv E_{1}\times\cdots\times E_{n}?$